# Posting the list data using AJAX in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I generated a list of check boxes with the help of a loop in the view

```
<div id = "MyForm">
    @for (int idx = 0; idx < Model.ListOfAbuseTypes.Count; idx++)
    { 
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.ListOfAbuseTypes[idx].IsChecked)
        @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ListOfAbuseTypes[idx].Description)
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ListOfAbuseTypes[idx].Description)       
    }
</div>
```

and later i tried to post that using ajax to controller

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#btnAjax').click(function () {
         var jsondata = $('#MyForm').serialize()
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Case/SaveReportSubstantiation',
            traditional: true,
            data: jsondata,
        })
    })
});
```

when i debug the jquery code the data in the variable jsondata is storing  as a string and that string looks like this.

```
Id=2028&ClientId=2028&FirstName=Athena&LastName=Balaban&Address.AddressLine1=650+W+Belden+&Address.AddressLine2=&Address.City=Chicago&Address.Zip5=60614&Address.Zip4=&Phone=&SSN=000221794&DOB=7%2F1%2F1933+12%3A00%3A00+AM&ListOfAbuseTypes=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BCMS.Models.Intake.viewAbuseType%5D&ClassificationId=0&IfUnableToSubstantiateId=0&DateofSubstantiation=&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B0%5D.Id=1&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B0%5D.Code=01&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B0%5D.IsChecked=false&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B0%5D.Description=Physical&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B1%5D.Id=2&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B1%5D.Code=02&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B1%5D.IsChecked=true&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B1%5D.IsChecked=false&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B1%5D.Description=Sexual&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B2%5D.Id=3&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B2%5D.Code=03&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B2%5D.IsChecked=false&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B2%5D.Description=Emotional&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B3%5D.Id=4&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B3%5D.Code=04&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B3%5D.IsChecked=false&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B3%5D.Description=Deprivation&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B4%5D.Id=5&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B4%5D.Code=05&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B4%5D.IsChecked=false&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B4%5D.Description=Passive+Neglect&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B5%5D.Id=6&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B5%5D.Code=06&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B5%5D.IsChecked=false&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B5%5D.Description=Confinement&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B6%5D.Id=7&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B6%5D.Code=07&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B6%5D.IsChecked=false&ListOfAbuseTypes%5B6%5D.Description=Financial+Exploitation&Summary=&AgencyName=&CompletedBy=&Email="
```

this is my controller ,its a dummmy one just to check whether the data is coming or not

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult SaveReportSubstantiation(viewReportOfSubstantiation jsonData)
{
    viewReportOfSubstantiation ReportSubstantiation = new viewReportOfSubstantiation();
    return PartialView();
}
```

When I put the cursor on the jsondata here everything is coming except the data from the list which i mentioned above.

My models are

```
Public  class viewReport
{

    public int Id { get; set; }


    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "First Name:")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name:")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    public List<viewAbuseType> ListOfAbuseTypes { get; set; }


    public viewReport()
    {
        this.ListOfAbuseTypes = new List<viewAbuseType>();
    }



}
```

and

```
public class viewAbuseType
{

    public int? Id { get; set; }





    [Display(Name = "Code")]

    public string Code { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Description")]

    public string Description { get; set; }


    public string DisplayText { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Is Delete?")]
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Is Checked?")]
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You need to show your model.

Comment: And as a side note, your do not need both `$(document).ready(function () {` and `$(function () {`, and you do not need `traditional: true,`

Comment: As Stephen mentioned, we need to see that model, I agree document ready not needed unless your script appears before your form tag. Problems I see are: you're sending a string from the client (not json) but default content type is form, not string. You're expecting an object at server (however not posting a form from client so how to map these values?), there's no json involved anywhere despite the name of variables and return from server is html not text as expected by client (since datatype is missing jQuery expects the default datatype which is text)

Comment: @StephenMuecke  now you can see my models

Comment: @derloopkat, Sorry, but some of what you have stated is wrong. OP's code for sending the data is correct (and will be send using the default `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`), and you do not need to specify the `dataType` option - if its omitted, the function works it out from the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data your sending includes

```
 ...&ListOfAbuseTypes=System.Collections.Generic.List%601%5BCMS.Models.Intake.viewAbuseType%5D&ClassificationId=0&....
```

which can only mean that that somewhere in your view you have included a form control that is trying to bind to the collection, for example

```
 @Html.HiddenFOr(m => m.ListOfAbuseTypes)
```

You cannot bind an input to a collection (only each property of each item in the collection), and what is happeing is the the `DefaultModelBinder` tries to set the value of `ListOfAbuseTypes` to that string (which of course fails).

Check you view and remove that input and your collection will bind correctly.

Not related, but:

1. Remove either `$(document).ready(function () {` or `$(function () {`
   from the script (both mean the same thing.
2. Remove `traditional: true,` from the ajax options (that is only
   applicable whe posting arrays of simple type
3. Use `url: '@Url.Action("SaveReportSubstantiation", "Case")',` to
   ensure your urls are always correctly generated

Comment: I really appreciate , its working now i removed the  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ListOfAbuseTypes) and it works , thank you so much. you saved the day